# Use python requests to login and upload a file on a django site. csrf token error

Tags: python, django, python-requests

I have a django website where login in is required to upload a file. The file is part of a model form field. Both login (auth) and file upload work well when running straight from the browser. However when using python requests, only login works and upload fails with a crsf error.

Below are code samples.

forms.py

`class DatabaseUploadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ["dbfile"]`

upload.html

```html
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <fieldset class="form-group">
        <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Upload Database</legend>
        {{ p_form}}
    </fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Update</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

login_and_upload_script.py

```
user = "user1"
password="passwrd1"
url_login='http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/login/'
url_upload='http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/upload/'
client = requests.session()
client.get(url_login)
csrftoken = client.cookies['csrftoken']
files={'dbfile':('files.db', open('file.db', 'rb'))}
login_data = {'username':user,'password':password, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken':csrftoken, 'next': 
url_upload}
r1=client.post(url_login,data=login_data)
print(r1.status_code) 
print('\n=================================================================\nLogged In......\nConti')


client.get(url_upload)
csrftoken2 = client.cookies['csrftoken']
files={'dbfile':('MARKSDB.db', open('MARKSDB.db', 'rb')), 'csrfmiddlewaretoken':csrftoken2}
r=requests.post(url_upload, files = files, headers=dict(Referer=url_upload))
print(r.status_code)
print(r.text)
print('\n=================================================================\nDone')
```

The output

```
200

=================================================================
Logged In......
Continue
403
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="NONE,NOARCHIVE">
  <title>403 Forbidden</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    html * { padding:0; margin:0; }
    body * { padding:10px 20px; }
    body * * { padding:0; }
    body { font:small sans-serif; background:#eee; color:#000; }
    body>div { border-bottom:1px solid #ddd; }
    h1 { font-weight:normal; margin-bottom:.4em; }
    h1 span { font-size:60%; color:#666; font-weight:normal; }
    #info { background:#f6f6f6; }
    #info ul { margin: 0.5em 4em; }
    #info p, #summary p { padding-top:10px; }
    #summary { background: #ffc; }
    #explanation { background:#eee; border-bottom: 0px none; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="summary">
  <h1>Forbidden <span>(403)</span></h1>
  <p>CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.</p>


  <p>You are seeing this message because this site requires a CSRF cookie when submitting forms. This cookie is required for security reasons, to ensure that your browser is not being hijacked by third parties.</p>
  <p>If you have configured your browser to disable cookies, please re-enable them, at least for this site, or for âsame-originâ requests.</p>

</div>

<div id="info">
  <h2>Help</h2>

    <p>Reason given for failure:</p>
    <pre>
    CSRF cookie not set.
    </pre>


  <p>In general, this can occur when there is a genuine Cross Site Request Forgery, or when
  <a
  href="https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/csrf/">Django's
  CSRF mechanism</a> has not been used correctly.  For POST forms, you need to
  ensure:</p>

  <ul>
    <li>Your browser is accepting cookies.</li>

    <li>The view function passes a <code>request</code> to the template's <a
    href="https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#django.template.backends.base.Template.render"><code>render</code></a>
    method.</li>

    <li>In the template, there is a <code>{% csrf_token
    %}</code> template tag inside each POST form that
    targets an internal URL.</li>

    <li>If you are not using <code>CsrfViewMiddleware</code>, then you must use
    <code>csrf_protect</code> on any views that use the <code>csrf_token</code>
    template tag, as well as those that accept the POST data.</li>

    <li>The form has a valid CSRF token. After logging in in another browser
    tab or hitting the back button after a login, you may need to reload the
    page with the form, because the token is rotated after a login.</li>
  </ul>

  <p>You're seeing the help section of this page because you have <code>DEBUG =
  True</code> in your Django settings file. Change that to <code>False</code>,
  and only the initial error message will be displayed.  </p>

  <p>You can customize this page using the CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW setting.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

=================================================================
Done

How do you avoid this error.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

{% csrf_token %} in upload.html
generates the following item in the HTML-document delivered to the client. The value changes with each GET request.

```
<input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="jw6POTYvAfmm1iXo5LfjoLyY2adlZKbwDlYZqaGOSCj8cEgtwAn6THQl3Yxv9sdE">
```

This is not visible if the doc is rendered in a browser.

You need to extract the value from the GET response and send it as csrfmiddlewaretoken in the POST request (assign the value to csrftoken2 in your login_and_upload_script.py script)

Sorry, I have no code snippet for that. I did this in LabVIEW.

Comment: I ended up just using crsf_exempt! But this works too. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you have to have an action attribute too, by default the POST call is sent on the current URL on which the form was rendered

```
<form method="POST" action='' enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks but added the action attribute too... getting the same error